# Multiple variable length lists inside ScrollView

Tags: android

Disclaimer: I'm mostly a backend developer, but I was called to an emergency with an android app, so the nuances of the framework are unknown to me.

Said that, I have the following requirement:

Show in a single long screen (vertically scrollable) the information coming from backend. This particular screen has two different sets of lists with the following layout

---

- main element 1
- main element 2
- ...

*References*

1. Reference 1
2. Reference 2
3. ...

---

(For clarification, main elements are links to further details of each, while references are plain text)

On previous cases I have used something like this (with only a single list)

```
 <ScrollView 
    ...
   >
      <RecyclerView 
        ...
       />
  </ScrollView>
```

using the adapter to show the elements.

(If this is a suboptimal approach, I'm open to suggestions)

But using two RecyclerViews causes weird behavior (like having two scrollable sections on screen), and on further investigation, it's advised to not use RecyclerView inside ScrollView at all, but I haven't found any alternative either.

Any help or pointer will be appreciated

Comment: Try to add `NestedScrollView`  instead of `ScrollView` and add `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` in both recyclerviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Geek provided the right answer on his comment. I'm just adding this to mark the question as solved.

> Try to add NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView and add android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" in both recyclerviews